# PHP variable not regenerating when publishing multiple posts at the same time

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, categories, automation

*Context*: I am building an automated system which will grab record from a database and immediately publish them en masse as a CPT. When they are being published, I have a function in the functions.php file of a child theme that should automatically set two categories to the post, a "fixed" one called 'People', and another one based on a column (categ) which is part of the record sent with the post.

My issue is that this second category (which should change per the contents of the record) is being permanently set for all the posts as the first one being processed. Is there a way to modify the code below to better specify that it should return the category found in that specific record? Is it possibly an issue with using the 'save_post' hook for publishing multiple posts at the same time?

**Content in functions.php**

```
function post_auto_categ( $post_ID ) 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    $post_type = 'people';

    $categname = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT categ FROM wp_people_posting");
    $categnum = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE name ='" . $categname ."'");

    $peoplenum = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE name ='People'");
    $post_categories=array($peoplenum, $categnum);

    if(get_post_type($post_ID)==$post_type) 
    {
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_categories );
    }
   return $post_ID;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_auto_categ' );
```

**Categories:**

[image]

**Attribute with category content:**

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit for clearer context:**

I have a table called 'wp_people_posting' in phpMyAdmin.
[image]

The records in this table are uploaded through a separate plugin which grabs the records from Google Drive and inserts them into this table all at once.

Each record found in this table are contents posted onto the website, one post per record, as seen below.

[image]

All posts are then placed in two categories, one which is always named "Abstracts" (*changed from previously mentioned People in a recent update*) and another which should depend on the contents of the column 'categ'. The same category name is already inserted as a category on the website.

[image]

Is there a way in which I can call a function that would set the second category for every single post according to the contents of that particular post/record's 'categ' column?

Aka rather than all of them having the same "Data Science" (as seen in the 4th image), I want to set them all individually, as below.

[image: Record in Database]

which would mirror as the category listed with the post

[image: Set category for post]

**Edit 2: Content in Publication Plugin**

Below is the whole plugin that I am using to create the CPT, grabbing the details from the table and inserting them:

```
if(!function_exists('add_action'))
{
    echo 'ERROR: ABSPATH UNDEFINED. Access to this file is not allowed.';
    exit;
}

function create_abstract_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Abstracts', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Abstract', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Student Abstracts', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Abstract', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
        'archives' => __( 'Abstract Archives', 'textdomain' ),
        'attributes' => __( 'Abstract Attributes', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Abstract:', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Abstracts', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Abstract', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Abstract', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Abstract', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Abstract', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Abstract', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_items' => __( 'View Abstracts', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Abstract', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'textdomain' ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'Featured Image', 'textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into Abstract', 'textdomain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Abstract', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list' => __( 'Abstracts list', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Abstracts list navigation', 'textdomain' ),
        'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter Abstracts list', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'Abstract', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => __( 'List of all the abstracts submitted by students from the Faculty of ICT', 'textdomain' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-text',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'post-formats', 'custom-fields'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
    register_post_type( 'abstract', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_abstract_cpt', 0 );

add_action( 'wp', 'insert_into_cpt');

function verify_existing_abstract_in_cpt() 
{

    $id_arrays_in_cpt = [];
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'abstract',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $id_arrays_in_cpt[] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'abstract_id', true);
    }
    return $id_arrays_in_cpt;
}

function query_abstract_post_table( $available_in_cpt ) 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'abstract_posts';
    if ( NULL === $available_in_cpt || empty($available_in_cpt) || 0 === $available_in_cpt) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
    } else {
        $ids = implode( ",", $available_in_cpt);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE abstract_id NOT IN ($ids)";
    }

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
    return $results;
}

function insert_into_cpt()
{
    $available_in_cpt = verify_existing_abstract_in_cpt();
    $database_results = query_abstract_post_table( $available_in_cpt );

    if (NULL === $database_results || empty( $database_results ) || 0 === $database_results) 
    {
        return;
    }

    //Insert into CPT
    foreach($database_results as $result) 
    {
        //Create post object
        $abstract_details = array(
            'post_title' => $result->title,
            'meta_input' => array(
                'abstract_id' => $result->abstract_id,
                'title' => $result->title,
                'author' => $result->author,
                'supervisor' => $result->supervisor,
                'cosupervisor' => $result->cosupervisor,
                'course' => $result->course,
                'categ' => $result->categ,
                'writeup' => $result->writeup,
                'firstabstractimage' => $result->firstabstractimage,
                'firstabstractimagecaption' => $result->firstabstractimagecaption,
                'secondabstractimage' => $result->secondabstractimage,
                'secondabstractimagecaption' => $result->secondabstractimagecaption,
                'ref' => $result->ref,
            ),
            'post_type'   => 'abstract',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        wp_insert_post( $abstract_details );
    }
}
```

These details are then taken by the `content.php` file and added into it directly with, for example, `esc_html(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'firstabstractimage', true))` *(I know that changing content.php to CPT content is not ideal, will be modifying soon to taking the post template from an `archive-abstracts.php` file)*

Comment: I've read this a few times and i don't understand what you're trying to do, or what the problem is. Can you edit your question and explain using different words?

Comment: @TomJNowell I have included an edit at the bottom. Hopefully this explains my situation further.

Comment: ok so the SQL query you made is the same for all posts, so it will always return the same values. It's unclear what `$categname` is and how it relates to the post you're trying to create. How do you know which `categ` in the people posting table is the one you need? And where does the `wp_people_posting` table come from? Also, inserting variables directly into an SQL query can cause injection attacks, but you can fix that by running the query through `$wpdb->prepare`

Comment: @TomJNowell Is there a way to make it different for every post? That is my main concern. $categname is just selecting the column 'categ' from the table wp_people_posting (found in a linked phpMyAdmin db). I want $categname to change for every published post, according to what is found in the related attribute 'categ'.

Comment: Also will add ```$wpdb->prepare``` thank you. I have never worked with databases and PHP so this is all quite new to me.

Comment: Without knowing more about what you're trying to do I do not know if it can be made different for every post, I do not understand how that table is meant to work. If I have post A, and there is a category for post A, what is that category supposed to be? How are they connected? Unless you explain that, it is impossible to write an answer, e.g. how do you know the post should have `Health` instead of `People`? Is there a phrase in the title? Are they written on a certain day? Is it just that the first post has the value in the first row, the next has the second etc? How does it know?

Comment: @TomJNowell I have re-edited "Edit for clearer context:" part above, hopefully it explains the process better. My main concern is that, with all the posts being published at the same time, I don't know how a function can be set to change the category for every single published post (based on the related text in 'categ' column of the record).

Comment: Hmmm, can you share the code that reads the table to create the posts? I do not believe the `save_post` hook is what you need and that there is a much simpler solution. Since you do not know which row the post is from, you can't retrieve the row and find the `categ`.

Comment: @TomJNowell Please find the requested code under "Edit 2: Content in Publication Plugin" above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `save_post` hook.

When you call `wp_insert_post`, it will return either a post ID or an error object. We can use this to then assign the category by taking `categ` from `$result`.

I imagine it would looks similar to this:

```php
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $abstract_details );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $result['categ'], 'category' );
}
```

You could also use the `post_category` parameter of `wp_insert_post` or the `tax_input` parameter.

Comment: Would this run within the foreach loop of the ```insert_into_cpt()``` function itself? And a final thing, what would 'category' in ```wp_set_object_terms``` actually be? Never used ```wp_set_object_terms``` before and quite confused from the WordPress developer resources.

Comment: the same place your current `wp_insert_post` call goes. `wp_set_object_terms` sets the terms on an object. The object is the post you just created, the term is a category name, and the taxonomy is the post category taxonomy. The same way that _a red car_ has an object ( the car ) that has a term ( red ) in a taxonomy ( colour ) ( `wp_set_object_terms( $car_id, 'red', 'colours' );` ). Look at your CPT registration, it says it accepts 2 taxonomies, `category` and `post_tag`, the third parameter is the taxonomy name, the second the term, etc, refer to the official doc for `wp_set_object_terms`

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well as your patience, this works completely. In case someone has the exact same issue as myself, set the ```$result``` in the above answer as my ```$abstract_details```, add ```['meta_input']``` before ```['categ']``` as well and place in same position as ```wp_insert_post``` call.